# Nestjs exception: Why does my server stop working after an HttpException is thrown?

Tags: node.js, docker, exception, nestjs

```
// my env
// package.json
"@nestjs/common": "^10.0.0",
"@nestjs/core": "^10.0.0",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^10.0.0",
"@nestjs/typeorm": "^10.0.1",
// os 
Mac m1
// dockerfile
FROM node:21
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start:dev
```

I don't understand why the server stops working after the exception is handled.

1. i use global filters.

```
// main.ts
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.useGlobalFilters(new HttpExceptionFilter());
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

this is my filter. ref: https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1

```
@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    console.log('filter');
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    const status = exception.getStatus();

    response.status(status).json({
      statusCode: status,
      message: exception.message,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      path: request.url,
    });
  }
}
```

okay. Now, when an exception occurs, the filter must detect it and respond.
I raised an exception and checked it using postman.

```
// studies.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class StudiesService {
  constructor(
    @InjectRepository(Study)
    private studiesRepository: Repository<Study>,
  ) {}
  async getStudyById(id: number): Promise<Study> {
    const study = await this.studiesRepository.findOneBy({ id: id });
    if (!study) {
      throw new NotFoundException(`getStudyById: Cannot find the ${id}`);
    }
    return study;
  }
  async deleteStudyById(id: number): Promise<void> {
    const deleteResult = await this.studiesRepository.delete(id);
    if (deleteResult.affected === 0) {
      throw new HttpException(`${id} not found.`, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
  }
}

// studies.controller.ts
@Controller('/studies')
export class StudiesController {
  constructor(private studiesService: StudiesService) {}
  @Get('/:id')
  async getStudyById(@Param('id') id: number): Promise<Study> {
    return this.studiesService.getStudyById(id);
  }
  @Delete('/:id')
  deleteStudyById(@Param('id') id: number) {
    this.studiesService.deleteStudyById(id);
  }
}

// studies.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Study])],
  controllers: [StudiesController],
  providers: [StudiesService],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
})
export class StudiesModule {}

// app.module.ts
@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRoot(typeORMConfig), StudiesModule],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

But a problem arises.
If I send an API request without a problem, you will receive a proper response.

```
// GET localhost:3000/api/studies/2
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "askkkkdf",
    "description": "world",
    "start": "2024-02-06T16:56:19.941Z"
}
```

However, if I make a request to raise an exception...

```
// DELETE localhost:3000/api/studies/100, id 100 not in my DB.
 /app/src/studies/studies.service.ts:36
       throw new HttpException(`${id} not found.`, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
             ^
 HttpException: 100 not found.
     at StudiesService.deleteStudyById (/app/src/studies/studies.service.ts:36:13)
     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

If I send a request after the following message appears in my docker console,
no matter which request I send, an Error: read ECONNRESET error appears. After checking the docker console, there are no more requests.
Why does this error occur?
The interesting thing is that if you make a GET request to raise an exception, the filter works, and the result is the same whether I raise the exception as an HttpException or NotFoundException.

Comment: I believe you need to `await` this.studiesService.deleteStudyById(id), else your controller will return response before your service throwing out the exception

Answer (score 0):

I must return anything such as 204.

```
async deleteStudyById(id: number): Promise<number> {
    const deleteResult = await this.studiesRepository.delete(id);
    if (deleteResult.affected === 0) {
      throw new HttpException(`${id} not found.`, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
    return HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT;
  }
```

Even when I was doing front-end development, I realized that whatever request was made from the back-end, a response value was given!